# Embedded Youtube videos float to the right when viewed on phone

Tags: html, css, youtube, alignment, center

I'm making a responsive website and I have a few Youtube videos on it. When I view my site on > 479px resolution, the videos stay at the center, but when I view on phone screen resolution or when I scale down my browser to < 480px, the videos float all the way to the right. Right now Im using  text-align: center to center the video.

Here's my code:

```css
 
 .youtube{
 text-align: center;
   
 }
```

```html
<p class="youtube">
   <iframe width="560" height="340" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Ubl3r5mGRtg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></br>

   <iframe width="560" height="340" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xgr38LWUf7w" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></br>
    <iframe width="560" height="340" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ylT54zdmGCk" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
   </p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add to your css:

```
iframe { max-width: 100%; }
```

And maybe fix the height with some media queries.